# Converting my application from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to convert my application from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2010. But I am facing an application execution at initialization 0xc0000005. My Visual Studio solution is a mix of C++ and C# projects.

I'd like to continue using .NET 2.0. I am using [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports). How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert one project at a time.

You should specify your problem a little more.

Given that the error is "0xc0000005" and without any more data, I could estimate that your issue is probably from one of your C++ projects' conversion.